# WP Page Navi Not Working in my Custom Query - Events Page Only

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm using the same custom wpquery format in my NEWS page. And my pagination uses `WP PAGE NAVI` plugin. It does work on my `NEWS PAGE` but doesnt work on my `EVENTS PAGE`.

Plugins used:

```
1. WP PAGE NAVI
2. EVENTS MANAGER
```

Problem: When i click page 2 or next page. The page becomes `404`:

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
global $wp_query; 
$old_query=$wp_query; 
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
?>
      <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged ));  ?>
      <?php while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php $EM_Event = em_get_event($post->ID, 'post_id'); ?>
      <div class="main-news-cont">
        <div class="event-posts">
          <div class="upcoming-date-cont2 fl">
            <div class="upcoming-d2"><?php echo get_the_date('d'); ?></div>
            <div class="upcoming-m-y2"><?php echo get_the_date('M Y'); ?></div>
          </div>
          <div class="news-title events-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> ">
            <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>
            </a></div>
          <div class="events-time-loc">
            <div class="events-time"> <span>Time</span>: 10:AM to 12:00PM</div>
            <div class="events-loc"> <span>Location:</span> <?php echo do_shortcode('[locations_list]'); ?> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
      <?php $wp_query=$old_query;?>
```

Also im not sure if i have to post this as a separate question. I cant seem to pull out the start and end time of my event in my loop: As of now it has static start time and end time in there.

Thanks! I really need you help guys!! Please!